# Is there an easy way to parse through a text file with 4 columns to sum/average values with a matching first value?

Tags: java

I've got a text file that I've trimmed extraneous data off of, leaving me with `4 columns`. The first acts as a `state identifier`, and each of the next three contain some `numerical information` about the *population* of that state.

This is my first time playing with `IO/file parsing` and I seem to be having trouble putting together a solution to determine which lines have the same state identifier then summing together the values of columns 2, 3 and 4.

**Example of what this may look like as input:**

```
01   123   456   789
01   456   789   012
```

*and so on*

**Example of what I'd like to see it become as output:**

`01   579  1245   801`

I've tried going line by line and `splitting` the contents of my input file to a `string array` then `Integer.parseInt()` to turn my string contents into integers.

Have just recently tried putting together a `while loop` to slowly loop through my data with the intention of creating an `array` of the values on that line only so I can store them for performing my `summations/averages`.

```
int stateCode = 01;
while (stateCode <= 56) {                   
    if (line.startsWith(Integer.toString(stateCode))) {  
                System.out.println(stateCode);                          
            String[] stringValues = line.split("    ");                 
        for (int i = 0; + i < stringValues.length; i++) {                                
                       System.out.println(stringValues[i]);             
               }
        }   
        stateCode++;            
    }
```

Described what I'd like to see above! Really feel like I'm getting closer on this thing but would love to see what kinds of solutions others may consider using. Appreciate the input, all!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for each line you read in you want to identify which state the numbers are for with the first value and then add the next 3 to the state's already existing values? Might be a job for a 2D array where arr[statecode][0-2] could hold the data.

Comment: Yup thats the goal. Columns 2-4 are each a different population statistic and the goal is to compile all values for state one together. I'll give a 2d array a try!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a general idea, which may facilitate your work.

```
01 123 456 789
```

This line can be represented as an `Entry<Integer, IntSummaryStatistics>`, the key is a state code, the value is a statistics about that state.

```
Integer stateCode = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.stream(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')).split(" "))
                                        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                                        .summaryStatistics();
```

Having these two values, you can form a recond and put it into a `Map`.

```
map.put(stateCode, statistics);
```

You proceed with next elements, and check if the statistics for the state being processed has already been calculated. If so, you calculate a new one, and merge the two.

```
map.compute(stateCode, (key, oldValue) -> {
    if (oldValue == null) {
        return statistics;
    }
    oldValue.combine(statistics);
    return oldValue;
});
```